# rsync: delete some files in destination not in source but not delete others

Tags: rsync, backup

Given two directories `/.../src` and `/.../des`,

- they share some subdirectories `share1` and `share2`
- `des` also has a subdirectory named `des1` which doesn't exist in `src`.

How can I perform file transfer from `src` to `des` (by `rsync` or other program you prefer), in order to

- update `share1` and `share2` in `des` according to their samename directories in `src`, including

  - deleting all the files that are in `des/share1` and `des/share2` but not in `src/share1` and `src/share2`,
  - adding all the files that are not in `des/share1` and `des/share2` but in `src/share1` and `src/share2`, and
  - updating all the files that are  in both `des/share1` and `src/share1`  or in both `des/share2` and `src/share2`,
- keep `des/des1` intact? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options. Both use `rsync`.

**Either:** Only update `share1` and `share2`, deleting unknown files in the target

```
rsync --dry-run -avP --delete .../src/share1 .../src/share2 .../des/
```

**Or:** Update everything in `des`, deleting unknown files in the target except for `des1`

```
rsync --dry-run -avP --delete --exclude '/des1' .../src/ .../des/
```

When you're happy with the result, remove `--dry-run`.

Comment: Thanks. Does `--exclude` option apply to both source and destination?

Comment: @Tim, yes unless you override it with `--delete-excluded`.

Comment: In my example, can --delete in your command be replaced with --delete-excluded?

Comment: @Tim you really need to look at the [man page for rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). If you `--delete-excluded` you will delete excluded items.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask: can --exclude in your command be replaced with --delete-excluded? I think they are the same in my example?

Comment: @Tim you can replace it if you like, but it will then delete the `des1` directory. I thought you wanted to keep that?

Comment: @Tim, oh I think I see what you're getting at. The `--delete --exclude` combination deletes items EXCEPT those excluded. The `--delete-excluded` item deletes items INCLUDING those excluded.

Comment: (1) Does --delete-excluded means delete those specified with --excluded, not excluded the following from delete. i.e. --delete-exclude means it will makes --excluded apply to source only not to the destination? (2) In your post, the first option is "Only update share1 and share2, deleting unknown files in the target". Does it mean deleting unknown files in the `.../des/share1` and `.../des/share2`? That will keep `.../des/des1` intact, because you specify the sources as `.../src/share1` and `.../src/share2`. If you specify the source as `.../src`, then `.../des/des1` will be deleted, correct?

Comment: @Tim try it with the `--dry-run` option, which tells `rsync` not to action any changes. Please consider asking these details as a new Question.